# Can I get warfarin in Tajikistan (or nearby?)

Tags: safety, health, tajikistan, dushanbe

I've run into a major problem, requiring urgent Warfarin.  However, am in Khorog, Tajikistan, and there's NONE in town, and the pharmacist at the hospital believes there to be none in the country, save for the 5 tablets in my bag.

My question is, **what would be the nearest city from Dushanbe that I can get a visa on arrival for (NZ passport), which would definitely stock Warfarin or coumadin**.

I have an entry visa for Russia if need be - if I hypothetically have to go to Moscow... but I'd rather not.

Comment: I think you really should fly to Moscow, as in this town you definitely will find that you need. As I know, no of near countries support visa issue on arrival. And no guaranties this tablets will be at that town.

Comment: Thinners ain't no joke. Take the safe route and go to a place you know can keep you running.

Comment: Are there alternatives to this medication? I was going to suggest asking on health.SE but it's only in definition. Might be worth committing to in any case: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health

Comment: Thanks guys.  It goes under coumadin and several other names, but just gave the full list of them to the hospital with no luck.  They gave me some Plavix, but it works a different way and don't think it's going to cut it - have emailed some doctors I know to double check, but otherwise I'm going to have to get my ass to Dushanbe for a flight ASAP!

Comment: this may sound obvious, but i assume you told them the generic name, warfrin, as well as the brand names, there's a chance that they don't stock brand name meds, but would stock generic versions.

Comment: I believe there are direct flights to Delhi from Dushanbe, and India has visas on arrival for NZ passports.  Plus you likely have less of a language barrier in India if you don't speak Russian.  There are also direct flights to Istanbul, and Turkey does not require a visa.

Comment: +1 for Istanbul. The Turkic countries ought to be well connected and anything you can't get in Istanbul is something you can't get anywhere.

Comment: Thanks everyone. After a sandstorm in Dushanbe cancelled my plane, I had to take a 16 hour taxi back here.  Finally managed to source what may well be the only supply in Tajikistan at a clinic in Dushanbe.  Will put more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Final answer: Basically almost no pharmacy in Tajikistan knows of Warfarin, Coumadin or other variants.

This includes the pharmacies at the CARDIOLOGY hospital in Dushanbe.

However, on the grounds of said hospital is the English-speaking Prospekt Medical Center (based from London).  They get requests for warfarin "on average, every 4 or so years" and as such have a small supply of warfarin tablets and heparin injections.

As far as the doctor on duty is aware (and from my investigations) this is probably the only location for warfarin in all of Tajikistan.

Comment: Cool story, bro.  Glad everything worked out for you.