# What does a Tajik GBAO permit look like?

Tags: permits, tajikistan, pamir-highway

To travel on the Pamir Highway in Tajikistan one needs a special GBAO permit, I got my Tajik visa today and it came with an extra stamp:

[image: stamp in the passport]

Is this the GBAO permit?

Comment: [It looks the part](http://learningbeyondborders.org/tajikistan), at least (courtesy of Google Images).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's it.  I just checked my passport, where mine is still in from three years ago, and can confirm mine looks like that too. They check it at the entrance to the area, a few hours out of Dushanbe, and then at many, many checkpoints along the way - at least to Khorog, which is as far as I got unfortunately, before [needing to turn back](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/983/101).

Enjoy the many tea stops, the crazy rides, cliffs, and spectacular scenery like this:

[image: Pamir Highway between Dushanbe and Khorog]
([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Transport-dush-khorog.jpg))

and keep an eye out for the odd overturned tank(!).

(edit) If you want an online source, [the link Gilles provided backs this up](http://learningbeyondborders.org/tajikistan).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I expected an answer from you on this. I will have more questions as soon as I get there.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf great, looking forward to seeing them, loved the country, was very disappointed to cut it short.